# RAID 5 Physical Disk shows Foreign status on Dell OpenManage

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, dell-poweredge, raid5, dell-openmanage

I have a DELL PowerEdge 2950 Server which has 6 Physical Hard Disks.

First 4 HDD are configured as RAID-5, and the rest two are configured as RAID-1.
From last week, third hard disk of RAID-5 shows status as "Foreign".

How can I clear this status, and rebuild the hard disk without affecting other hard disks, or RAID configurations.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the Foreign flag from the drive you would need to navigate to the Perc configuration in Dell Open Manage -> Information/Configuration link at the top of the page, Clear Foreign Configuration from the drop-down menu of available tasks.

You can refer to this link: https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/how-to-clear-a-foreign-state-from-a-replacement-sas-drive-on-a/td-p/3558875

Also, make sure that you have data backup doing anything with the RAID array.

Additionally, update all drivers and firmware to the latest versions.